# Scala implicit conversion on Ints

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Assume that I have following method:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(Ring(2) + Ring(3) + Ring(-1) + Ring(10))
  }
```

which produces:

> ( [2] left-> ( [-1] left-> null, right-> null), right-> ( [3] left->
>   null, right-> ( [10] left-> null, right-> null)))

I want to write an implicit conversion which allows me to write the code in the following way:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val r :Ring = 2 + 3 + (-1) + 10
    println(r)
  }
```

but following implicit method

```
  implicit def intToRing(x :Int): Ring = {
    new Ring(x)
  }
```

Works in this way this first it sums up all elements and then create Ring what produces:

> ( [14] left-> null, right-> null)

Is it possible to implement 'not greedy' implicit conversion which will make what I want?

Comment: What is your desired outcome when calling `main`? `Ring(14)`?

Comment: ( [2] left-> ( [-1] left-> null, right-> null), right-> ( [3] left-> null, right-> ( [10] left-> null, right-> null)))

Comment: It's not clear to me how `println(Ring(2) + Ring(3) + Ring(-1) + Ring(10))` gets printed as `( [2] left-> ( [-1] left-> null, right-> null), right-> ( [3] left-> null, right-> ( [10] left-> null, right-> null)))`. Could you please say more?

Comment: I have tostring method overriden, but it is not much relevant that's why i didnt pasted it. See the answer of @shadowslands he got the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this by explicitly casting the first Int:

```
val r = (2: Ring) + 3 + (-1) + 10
```

this forces the compiler to look for a way to add "3" to a `Ring`, which should force the implicit conversion, whereas otherwise it can happily use integer addition without needing to look for an implicit conversion.

The only other way I can think of to do it would be to provide `Ring` with an alternative method name (either directly, or via an implicit wrapper class or the like), eg:

```
def +^(other: Ring): Ring = this + other
```

and use that operator:

```
val r = 2 +^ 3 +^ (-1) +^ 10
```